# Xcode stuck at time of app Distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store

I am facing an issue while submitting my app from Xcode 5.1.1 to the App Store. The app is running fine on iPhone and iPad.

First I create archive with Xcode. Archive is successfully created & shows in Organizer.

After archive I have done the validate. It pass the validation. Now archive file of app in Organizer is showing status pass validation.

After this, I have clicked on distribute and selected submit app to app store. I have selected provisioning files as well.

I am stuck here. And I have never seen any progress bar where I can see the submission progress or something like that. Xcode is stuck at "Your application is being uploaded." I am waited for 10-15 minutes but status is not changed. I spend many hours to google it & find many answer but none work for me.

Comment: restart xcode and do again...

Comment: @Fahim Parkar I tried many times, but not work for me now it shows alert message A server with the specified hostname could not be found. I reset wi-fi many time but not get any progress.

Comment: Submitting an app with Xcode can be buggy sometimes. You can try to use `Application Loader` (available trough your `iTunes Connect account`) instead. Or maybe the Apple servers are down for now ?

Comment: @user2831506 : keep trying after 2 hours... that's apple problem... they are facing some problem. when it is resolved, your app will get resolved...